# Pose Detection is not working in android ionic react app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, mediapipe

```
interface CustomOptions {
  runningMode?: string;
  numPoses?: number;
  smoothLandmarks?: boolean;
  maxNumFaces?: number;
  minDetectionConfidence?: number;
  minTrackingConfidence?: number;
}

const UserPose: React.FC = () => {
  const webcamRef = useRef<Webcam>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const poseRef = useRef<Pose>();
  const landMarkRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializePoseDetection = async () => {
      const pose = new Pose({
        locateFile: (file: string) => {
          return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/pose@0.2/${file}`;
        },
      });

      const options: CustomOptions = {
        smoothLandmarks: true,
        runningMode: "VIDEO",
        maxNumFaces: 1,
        minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
        minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
      };

      pose.setOptions(options);
      pose.onResults(onResults);
      poseRef.current = pose;

      // Initialize camera
      if (webcamRef.current && webcamRef.current.video) {
        const camera = new cam.Camera(webcamRef.current.video, {
          onFrame: async () => {
            if (webcamRef.current && webcamRef.current.video) {
              await pose.send({ image: webcamRef.current.video });
            }
          },
          width: 1280,
          height: 720,
        });
        camera.start();
      }
    };

    initializePoseDetection();

    return () => {
      // Cleanup
      if (poseRef.current) {
        poseRef.current.close();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  function onResults(results: any) {
    // <IonLabel>{(JSON.stringify(results.poseLandmarks))}</IonLabel>
    const canvasElement = canvasRef.current;
    if (canvasElement) {
      const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
      if (canvasCtx) {
        // Set canvas size
        canvasElement.width = results.image.width;
        canvasElement.height = results.image.height;

        // Draw video feed
        canvasCtx.drawImage(
          results.image,
          0,
          0,
          canvasElement.width,
          canvasElement.height
        );
        
        // Check if pose landmarks are available
        if (results.poseLandmarks && results.poseLandmarks.length > 0) {
          // Scale landmarks to fit the canvas
          const landmarks = results.poseLandmarks.map((landmark: any) => ({
            x: landmark.x * canvasElement.width,
            y: landmark.y * canvasElement.height
          }));
          
          drawLandmarks(
            canvasCtx,
            results.poseLandmarks,
            { color: 'red', lineWidth: 2, radius: 3 }
          );
        
          drawConnectors(
            canvasCtx,
            results.poseLandmarks,
            mediapipePose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
            { color: '#3240CF', lineWidth: 2 }
          );
         
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Webcam
        ref={webcamRef}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginRight: "auto",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: "center",
          zIndex: 9,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          // transform: "rotate(90deg)"
        }}
      />
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginRight: "auto",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: "center",
          zIndex: 9,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      ></canvas>
      <div ref={landMarkRef}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the code that works on web.According to the official mediapipe documentation you are supposed to add a dependency into your build.gradle which I did,yet I cant get this code to work on the emulator.It runs on the emulator but for some reason I cannot see the landmark points and the connectors on my phone screen.Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried on a real device?